# How to output structured error information in bazel rule?

Tags: bazel

Compiler error messages usually include lots of human parseable information about the underlying error. I have custom rules in which I would like to additionally expose this information in a machine parseable manner. This would allow things like integration with my editor showing me the locations that need to be fixed.

What is the recommended way of doing this? The best thing that I can come up with is to have a fairly simple structure that meshes well with the human readable part and include it in stdout/stderr and parse that. But this seems much more error prone than including a machine parseable output. But given that actions fail in a binary fashion, there cannot be any output files available, and I cannot think of any other mechanism to get data out.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Build Event Protocol](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/build-event-protocol.html). Consuming "Progress" messages could be useful here.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are suggesting. It seems that the progress messages are just stderr and stdout of the bazel process [doc](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/buildeventstream/proto/build_event_stream.proto#L225). I could instead just parse the ActionExecuted's stdout and stderr [doc](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/buildeventstream/proto/build_event_stream.proto#L415). But those are supposed to be human readable and not machine readable which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Ah indeed, you're right. I don't think Bazel supports this now. The BEP is probably the way forward, but the feature you need (emitting custom events) doesn't seem to be supported yet. I suggest filing a feature request.

Comment: Filed: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/6018. I'll probably parse stderr for now.